# Laravel Route goes to Controller but does not display data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created the following route

```
Route::resource('posts','PostController');
```

Now I'm trying to create a custom route

```
Route::get('posts/trashed','PostController@trashed')->name('posts.trashed');
```

When the link `posts/trashed` is clicked, it goes to the `PostController@trashed`, but the controller shows blank page without any errors.

So changed the custom route to

```
`Route::get('post/trashed','PostController@trashed')->name('posts.trashed');
```

by simply changing the `posts/trashed` to `post/trashed` and the controller works fine.

Can someone explain what the issue is.

Comment: If you're defining the `Route::get('posts/trashed')` route after the `Route::resource('posts')` definition you should move if before. Becase the resource definition will define a get `posts/{post}` route that will match `trashed` as a post ID which is defined as `post` in the resource route.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Solution was hidden deep inside the Laravel Documentation . https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

If it becomes necessary to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond the default resource routes, you should define those routes before your call to `Route::resource:`

Re-ordering will solve the issue.

```
Route::get('posts/trashed','PostController@trashed')->name('posts.trashed');
Route::resource('posts','PostController');
```

Answer (score 0):

The resource route has some routes inside it own.

So this route:

> Route::resource('posts','PostController');

contains this route :

> Route::get('posts/{post_id}',PostController@show)

So it has conflict with your route

*Route::get('posts/trashed','PostController@trashed')->name('posts.trashed');*

**Solution 1:**

bring your route upper than resource

I mean:

> Route::get('posts/trashed','PostController@trashed')->name('posts.trashed'); <-- first 
>   Route::resource('posts','PostController');

**Solution 2:**

As you mentioned use another url (like post/trushed)

**Solution 3 :**

Add exception for resource.

Route::resource('posts', 'PostController')->except([
    'show'
]);